# How to define the help of the CLI program in the __doc__?

Tags: python, documentation-generation, command-line-interface

I would like to do something like this :

```
def main():
    """
    Display Information about a Google Calendar

     -u --user login     Google Login
     -p --pass password  Google Password
     -d --debug          Set DEBUG = True
     -h --help           Display this help
    """

    print(__doc__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But the answer is : `None` ... Why ?

Comment: but better way would be to use http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html

Comment: Ok, I was using getopt. But optparse should much better for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the help that you want to print is "global", you might find it more logical to put it as the main documentation for your program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Display Information about a Google Calendar
...
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print __doc__
```

`__doc__` is a global variable that contains the documentation string of your script.

Comment: Ok, now I see the difference, but what is the best todo ?

Comment: @Natim What do you want `pydoc my_prog` to display? If you want it to first display the documentation for your program as a whole, it's simpler to use the *global* doc string.  If you don't to that, the reader has to guess that the doc for main() is the doc for your program.

Answer (score 4):

Because `__doc__` is an *attribute of the function*, not a local variable. You need to refer to it as `main.__doc__` like this:

```
def main():
    """Display Information about a Google Calendar

    ..."""
    print(main.__doc__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```